# Hide and reveal certain elements on click with CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor

I am creating a wordpress website with elementor and I am struggling to implement the proper Javascript code and CSS code for revealing only a certain combination of elements on clicking a button.

For example, when I select the first picture of the black bike, I would like to only display "Panigale V4 SP2," the black picture of the bike, one "view more" button, and one set of descriptions.

Here is the site https://aleksanderm4.sg-host.com/

Here is the code I have added thus far:

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.control-area > .elementor-element').on('click', function() {

    var index = $(this).index() - $('.control-area > .elementor-element').eq(0).index()

    $('.control-area > .elementor-element').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')

    $('.details-area').each(function() {
      $(this).children('.elementor-element').hide()
      $(this).children('.elementor-element').eq(index).show()
    })

  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --activeC: #ffffffbf;
}

.details-area>.elementor-element:nth-child(2),
.details-area>.elementor-element:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}

.bike-bg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.control-area>.elementor-element.active {
  background-color: var(--activeC) !important;
}

selector .elementor-element {
  position: static !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is best to place your code into your post using the snippet tool. This way, we can test it. However, we also need to see your HTML.

Comment: @Millhorn Hey thanks for your reply. How do I use the snippet tool? Also, the html is all in a drag-and-drop builder. Should I use the inspect tool and send over all of it?